# IE6 added a large left offset to my element?

Tags: css

I have the below in FF

[image]

But in IE6, I get

[image]

In debugBar, I get

[image]

Whats with the large offset.

http://jsfiddle.net/eteQ7/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bug in IE6 known as ["Doubled Float-Margin Bug"](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html). IE6 will double a left margin applied to a floated block element.

In order to avoid this behavior, you should use the fix suggested in [this article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html), adding a display:inline; property to the element, e.g. in a CSS stylesheet loaded only for IE6 using [conditional comments](http://www.impressivewebs.com/conditional-comments/).